# Класс для работы с БД (ООП PHP)

Tags: php

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, нормальный класс для работы с БД (mysqli)

Comment: вы не поверите, но **MySQLi** очень класный класc для работы с БД **MySQL**

Comment: Мне вот этот оЧень понравился - [Krugozor/Database](https://github.com/Vasiliy-Makogon/Database)

Answer (score 2):

Таких много в сети, ну например

[PHP класс для удобной и безопасной работы с MySQL](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165069/)

Answer (score 0):

Найти готовые решения просто, например в https://packagist.org/?q=mysqli.
Написать для себя тоже не составляет труда. Я себе запилил минималистичный интерфейс, сокращающий код стандартных операций https://github.com/EgorBanin/phpmysql